# Spinner detecting close event

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have this spinner with a list of music items. Upon clicking the music items, music will play and stop when user selects any music items.

The question is how to stop the music if user presses the back button?

I have tried to find methods that is called when spinner is closed. Can't seem to find any though. Am I missing anything obvious?

Please help!! 
thanks

If it matters, my spinner is called from a fragment.

```
    musicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int i, long l) {
                Log.v("music spinner","Item selected");
            if (mp.isPlaying())
                mp.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                Log.v("music spinner","Item not selected");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

When the user selects the home button of the back button, the activity and, incidentally the fragment, will get a call to `onPause` among other methods. That may be a good place to detect when to stop the music.

Comment: yes but the spinner may be closed with the fragment still running, so that won't capture my event either

Comment: This may be what you need then:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't detect if we press the back button

Comment: You could listen to the key events: within the fragment... `getView().setOnKeyListener(listener)`

Comment: ok, i tried your suggestion but that method was not triggered.

Comment: it seems like that method can't detect back button pressed

Comment: Maybe override `onBackPressed()` in the parent activity and cascade the event to the given fragment.

Comment: Tried that too. But it can't seem to detect the back button press on spinner coming from fragment

Comment: Actually, the back button on the Spinner will simply dismiss the spinner dialog. So it should call either of the methods inside `OnItemSelectedListener`. Btw, can we see some of your code? (as much as possible)

Comment: I added the codes using your suggestion of using onItemSelectedListener above. When I select any item within the list, the message will be shown, but if i pressed back. Nothing is display on log cat

Comment: It will only report back when the selection changes. So if you have nothing selected and nothing else is selected there is no changes to report.

Comment: yes, so the problem is when we press back. probably doesn't get captured by the onItemSelectedListener event that you were suggesting. Its ok, I decided to use another fragment instead of the spanner instead.